# Android Cancel long operation (Asynctask,thread...?)

Tags: android, long-integer, operation

I tried `AsyncTask`, Thread and Handler but i don't get it.

The method `readXML()` takes about 1-2 minutes and i only need a way to cancel this operation. All the solutions I've found were for short time operations (set flag, check flag and break).

### Edit

```
protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( Context... params ){
        try{
            preparing = true;
            readXML();
            preparing = false;
        } catch( Exception e ){
            Log.i("test", e.getMessage() );
        }
        return "COMPLETE!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(){               
        super.onCancelled();
    }

}

// ....
_initTask = new InitTask();
_initTask.execute(this);

// ....
_initTask.cancel(true);
```

Comment: Try to split your 1-2 minutes task into iterations of ~200ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that onCancelled is only invoked **after** doInBackground returns. So you need to check for isCancelled from within your readXML operation. See extract from docs (from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) below...

> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause
>   subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. After invoking this
>   method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be
>   invoked after doInBackground(Object[])
>   returns. To ensure that a task is
>   cancelled as quickly as possible, you
>   should always check the return value
>   of isCancelled() periodically from
>   doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

Comment: Torid is right. In current Java thread implementation, there is no safe way to stop a running thread outside the thread. See Java doc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html, all the stop()/destroy() call have been deprecated. The solution is to break your readXML() call into a series small chunk of work. In your thread, you need to check isCancelled() after each chunk of work, and end the thread if the work has been cancelled.